# EditText Android can't create object by id

Tags: android

I am trying to access the editText that is in the box... I am trying to create a object for it, but for some reason it is not working, I am really really new to Android so be it's a little confusing for me.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText txt = new (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.editText1);

    }

}
```

and here is the XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

I am getting a syntax error on `new` and method is undefined for `findViewByID` for type `MainActivity`

Comment: "it is not working" what is not working?  are you getting an error?

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I put the error at the end, if you read the whole thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `new`:

```
EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

This actually is a *cast*, meaning you tell the compiler that the object that is returned by `findViewById` not only is a `View`, which the method is declared to return,  but a specific subclass of `View` called `EditText`.

This line does not actually create a new `View`, but picks a `View` out of the `Activity`'s content view you set by calling `setContentView()`.

The id you pass as the function's argument is used to identify the `View` that you want to be picked out of the content view.

Comment: Just to explain, you don't need the "new" when you use findViewByID bcs the object was already in your layout, so there is no need to create an instance of the EditText...

Comment: Was still writing that, but it's now in my answer.

Comment: @FD_ Thank you! Also, I figured out it shouldn't be `ID` it should be`Id`

Comment: You're right, corrected my answer. Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
EditText txt = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.editText1);
```